# About table HTML float left and always on top

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm using a `<table>` something like below

```
<table width="45%" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" style="float: left; margin:2px;">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img/default.jpg" style="width:170; height:auto;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**The problem is: how do I make it always on top like this picture without space like my first picture**

Here the example table of what I want:

[image: Here the example table what i want]

Comment: Don't use a table, instead use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two `div`s beneath each other and add for each cell other divs inside of the two main divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "div" tag and that will divide your table to any shape that you want and you will make it like that:-

```
<div style="width:100px; height:auto; clear:both">
```

your input here.

```
</div>
```

that is for example then put your divide with the same format above but change the style and let the clear attribute like that,This will Separate your divide and will not attach it to any other divide.

I hope that will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    For placing table at the top use margin in css file set it 0 .
    **margin: 0px;**
See this example 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


<table border="1" class="myfirsttabel">

<thead>

    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Mobileno</th>


</thead>


<tbody>

<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    
<table border="1" class="tabel">

<thead></thead>

    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Mobileno</th>


<tbody>

<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    

</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>   new table</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>
</tbody>

</table>



</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td>    My Name is Varun</td>
<td> My email id isvarun@gmail.com</td>
<td> My Mobile No is 8903527945 </td>

</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

[image]
 **and css file**